# How to remove/hide action column in related list for specific profiles?

Tags: related-list

I would like to remove action column from related list view based on user profiles. Is it possible? If so then can you provide an example?

Comment: About the only way I can think this might be possible is by having different page layouts for the different profiles.

Comment: @Dave Humm I am unable to remove the action column in page layouts. If that is possible then what you suggested would suit me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the action column for specific profiles using the pageblocktable as shown below.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:detail subject="{!Contact.Id}" relatedList="{!IF($Profile.Name == 'Investor User',false,true)}"/>
<apex:pageBlock title="Contributions" rendered="{!IF($Profile.Name == 'Investor User'),true,false)}">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contact.Contributions__r}" var="item" >
        <apex:column value="{!item.Date__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!item.Type__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!item.Amount__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock title="Distributions" rendered="{!IF($Profile.Name == 'Investor User'),true,false)}">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contact.Distributions__r}" var="item1" >
        <apex:column value="{!item1.Year__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!item1.Date__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!item1.Amount__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to remove the action column on related lists in page layouts declaratively, the number of actions available will depend on the user's Profile and its permissions on the child object, a profile with read only access will be the only one that displays no actions in the column.

It is possible through VisualForce pages replacing the standard page layouts.

Comment: I have given only read access to both parent as well as related child object yet I am able to see the "Action" column in related list view. It doesn't show edit or delete buttons but it shows as a blank column with the header text alone.

Comment: As I stated in the answer it is not possible to remove the actions column, only to vary the types of actions available to the user by their profile permissions.

Comment: I was able to accomplish it using pageblocktable and rendered attribute. I have posted my answer.

Comment: So it is possible with VF, which I suspected but not declaratively. Will update my answer accordingly.